# How to configure DC automatically when use Spring Cloud Consul?

Tags: spring-cloud-consul

When use Spring Cloud and Consul to do the service discovery, if a service wants to access another service which is located in different DCs, the DC name must be specified in the configuration like following:

```
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.datacenters.STORES=dc-west
```

In which STORES is a service name and dc-west is a DC name.

I think the ideal situation is that the DC info of any service can be acquired automatically, not be configured via any configuration file or configuration service.

**So my question is that will this DC auto-discovery mechanism be provided in the future? Or can be achieved in an another way currently?**

Comment: Also interested in an answer to this question. For now we have to do it manually/ourselves?